# Jquery mobile style backward compatibility issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, backwards-compatibility

The following style classes are not working in the recent versions (1.3.x) of Jquery mobile. But they worked fine in earlier versions. What am I missing?

```
ui-corner-tr
ui-corner-tl
ui-corner-br
ui-corner-bl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue reported with regards to this on jQuery gitHub.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5511

They say that it was removed on purpose and advise what should be used now.